# Python 3.4 - Installing Kivy Error

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to install Kivy on Python 3.4 using the instructions here: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

I'm on the installing dependencies step, where it gives me this error: http://prntscr.com/a5rk5k

Initially I tried just going ahead to the last step (python -m pip install kivy) and it looked like it worked fine, but then I tried import kivy in a Visual Studio project and it said "Unable to resolve "kivy""

Any ideas anyone?  Keep in mind, I had Python 3.5 installed (which kivy does not work with) before now and set to default, but I changed the path in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right with your kivy installation, use `python -m pip list` to check what packages are missing and (re)install them, one-by-one would be the best for debugging. And also you've pasted it wrong, so the `kivy.deps.gstreamer` was read as a separate comand and not a package for `pip`

For simple installing of kivy just follow the install docs or if you don't mind having another folder or reinstalling python for new kivy&python try [KivyInstaller](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller) which hopefully makes the whole process beginnerproof. You enter what you need in the beginning and then wait.